# How to get all children of several nodes in tree structure?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, hierarchical-data

I have a table with hierarchical structure like this:

```
 Create Table tbl1 
 (
     AccountID  NVARCHAR(100), 
     ID int, 
     ParentID int
 );

 INSERT INTO tbl1 
 VALUES ('11', 1, Null), ('12', 2, Null), ('13', 3, Null),
        ('11/11', 4, 1), ('11/12', 5, 1), ('11/111', 6, 1),
        ('11/11/001', 7, 4), ('11/11/002', 8, 4), ('12/111', 9, 2),
        ('12/112', 10, 2);
```

How to get all children of some nodes from tbl1 in tree structure, according to an other table (`FilteringTbl`) like this:

```
 AccountID  
 ---------
 11/11
 12
 13
```

In other words I want to create a SQL query to get all children of nodes 11/11 and 12 and 13 from my first table (tbl1) in SQL Server 2008.
Main tables have more than 5000 records. (tbl1 5400 records and filteringtbl 1500 records)

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;with C
as (
    select  AccountID,
            ID,
            ParentID,
            0 as [level]
    from    tbl1
    where   ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Filteringtbl)
    union all
    select  I.AccountID,
            I.ID,
            I.ParentID,
            C.[level] + 1 as [level]
    from    tbl1 as I
            inner join C on
                C.ID = I.ParentID
)
select  *
from    C
```

Comment: My tables have more than 5000 records therefore that isn't suitable answer for my problem.

Comment: Do you want to display all 5000  record or one ID you specify?Can you comment the exact requirement

Comment: I want to filter tbl1 according to filteringtbl (tbl1 5400 records and filteringtbl 1500 records). thanks

Comment: Just we need to replace the with sub Query as specified above or You can join with the filtering table based on the id But subquery has better performance